# Delete wget download if incomplete in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wget

When I download jpegs from an unreliable website, the downloads are often incomplete.  Is there a wget option to delete incomplete downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [exit status](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) of `wget`

```dos
set "output=x:\somewhere\myFile.dat"
wget -O "%output%" "http://somewhere.com/this"
if errorlevel 1 del "%output%" 2>nul
```

Or using conditional execution operator `||` (execute next command if the previous fails)

```dos
set "output=x:\somewhere\myFile.dat"
wget -O "%output%" "http://somewhere.com/this" || ( 2>nul del "%output%" )
```

**note**: Of course, you don't need the variable, just included to avoid having to write the same file name in both commands.